# Why does this .dll have weird letters in ILSpy?

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling, reflector, ilspy

I'm using ILSpy to look at a .dll. A Majority of the classes are in english, but some of the classes are in the weird letters that I can't explain. I'm wondering if there is an error with the .dll or ILspy or if you it needed to be decompiled differently.

[image]

Comment: please include image to question, not link

Comment: @Alex fyi you need a certain amount of rep for images, otherwise they just appear as links.

Answer (score 6):

Because the code has been obfuscated, it's a way of making the code so hard to understand that it deters reverse engineering.

Usually PreEmptive's Obfuscation tool comes in Visual Studio, check it out. You could also try Market Place, Nuget & Visual Studio Gallery for more.

If you wish to de-obfuscate the DLL it might be possible with an old copy of the code and refactoring based on that. Otherwise you will find that Obfuscation is typically one way, eg renaming a `btnSave` to `a1` is irreversible​.

Comment: Is there a way I can compared this code to an older version of the code. The old version wasn't obfuscated and I'm able to read the code.

Comment: It will be painstakingly​ difficult to compare and almost impossible to de-obfuscate, they may have even baked their own cryptography in as well.

Comment: See my edit you might be in luck with an old copy of the code and a lot of refactoring!